# Lighting slds-box Add Text

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, css, slds

**How does the box add text?**

**I did not find the relevant style in [Lightning Design System](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/).**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could provide your code snippets? You could try slds-box_border should work  similarly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no ootb slds style that seems to do this, however, this is very basic HTML/css. You can easily achieve this by setting a negative margin to an element:

Template.html

```
<div>
  <h3>Title</h3>
</div>
```

.css

```
div{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

h3{
    width: 30px;
    margin-top:-12px;
    margin-left:5px;
    background-color : white;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is standard `legend` tag that is used with `fieldset`. You can read more about it here.

Because this is standard `HTML` functionality you can't find any info on it in Lightning Design System